# sshpass command will not recognize variable file

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, sshpass

```
sql_string=$(sshpass -p $ldappw ssh $ldapuser@$ssh_host 'mysql --skip-column-names '${db_info}' databasename < '"'${environment}'_final_table_selects.sql > '${environment}'_table_results.txt"'')
```

When trying to run this command I get the error:

```
ash: home_final_table_selects.sql: No such file or directory
```

Which is ironic, because the file does exist in the directory. I'm thinking there is an issue with sshpass and the quoting, but not sure how to fix it because the error it gives is false.

Comment: This is maddeningly long. Can you break it down? Like discarding the `sshpass` part and just do the `ssh` part interactively? Does that work? "The file does exist in the directory" — you mean the remote directory or the local directory?

Comment: are you saying that `sshpass` is broken? Not likely. Error messages are a matter of context. As I don't have your environment to test with, Either `home_final_table_selects.sql` exists on the remote dir, but is being evaluated in the local shell (where it doesn't exist), OR the other way around. As 4ae1e1 suggests, just do the ssh part, and see if that works. Also get comfortable with using `set -vx` for shell debug/trace. For testing, you might want to incorporate `local` and `remote` in your filenames. Good luck.